# Is there any way to clear cache and view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

In localhost new code works fine, but not in the server. It loads previous pages. how to clear cache and view page using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Server stats? Apache, op_cache, varnish etc. could be anything :D

Answer (score 0):

The cache file will be written to your `application/cache` folder.

If you need to manually delete the cache, you can use the `delete_cache()` method:

For more details you can refer below link

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html